# How to show that if the language L is regular, then L' is regular?

Tags: grammar, regular-language

Let L be any regular language and a ∈ Σ. How to show that the language L'={uav  | uv ∈ L} is regular too?

Wikipedia says a way to proove it is to lead it back to a regular language but I don't understand how to do that in this case. Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to show this. I think an argument whereby we construct a DFA is particularly easy to visualize.

Imagine a DFA for your language L. Let's call it `M`. Imagine it sprawled out in diagram form on a table. Now, imagine making a copy of `M` and spreading it out next to M on the table. Call it `M'`.

Now - from `M`, add a new transition from state `q` of `M` to the corresponding state `q'` of `M'`. The transition is on the symbol `a`.

Now, consider the aggregate machine whose start state is the start state of `M` and whose accepting states are the accepting states of `M'`. This machine starts out accepting strings in `L`, then accepts an `a` somewhere in the middle, and then continues accepting strings in `L` from where it left off. This is the language we were going for and we have defined a perfectly reasonable NFA for it. Since any language accepted by an NFA is regular, our language is regular.